# Sum of consecutive numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was wondering if there a way to figure out the number of ways to express an integer by adding up consecutive natural numbers.

For example for $N=3$ there is one way to express it
$1+2 = 3$

I have no idea where to start so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Would for any odd number $N$ the sum of the two integers that bracket half that number count as one solution?  Or as two?

Comment: Consecutive integers or consecutive naturals?

Comment: @Meelo sorry, I meant consecutive natural numbers. I'll edit it in the question

Comment: The sum of the natural numbers from $a$ to $b$ inclusive is $\frac{(a+b)(b-a+1)}{2}$.

Comment: See OEIS sequence A001227, https://oeis.org/A001227

Comment: The basic result is that $n$ can be represented this way if and only if $n$ not a power of $2$, I believe.

Comment: Presumably, you allow for more than $2$ consecutive numbers?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yeah, can have any number of consecutive numbers

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think you meant `(b-a+1)`. Otherwise the sum will be negative

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The sum of the integers from $1$ to $n$ is $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Hence, the sum of the integers from $m+1$ to $n$ is simply $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}-\dfrac{m(m+1)}{2}$. So, if the sum of the integers from $m+1$ to $n$ is $N$, then

$\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}-\dfrac{m(m+1)}{2} = N$

$(n^2+n) - (m^2+m) = 2N$

$(n-m)(n+m+1) = 2N$

Hence, $n-m$ and $n+m+1$ are complementary factors of $2N$. Clearly, $n-m$ is smaller than $n+m+1$, and since $(n+m+1)-(n-m) = 2m+1$, the factors have opposite pairity.

For any $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that $2N = f_1f_2$, $f_1 > f_2$ and $f_1$, $f_2$ have opposite parity, we can solve $n+m+1 = f_1$ and $n-m = f_2$ to get $n = \dfrac{f_1+f_2-1}{2}$ and $m = \dfrac{f_1-f_2-1}{2}$.

Therefore, the number of ways to write $N = (m+1)+(m+2)+\cdots+(n-1)+n$ is simply the number of ways to factor $2N$ into two distinct positive integers with opposite parity.

Suppose $2N = 2^{k_0+1}p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$ where $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_r$ are distinct odd primes. There are $(k_1+1)(k_2+1)\cdots(k_r+1)$ ways to divide the odd primes between $f_1$ and $f_2$. There are $2$ ways to give all $2$'s to one of the factors $f_1$, $f_2$. However, we need to divide by $2$ since this overcounts cases in which $f_1 < f_2$. Also, we need to subtract out the one trivial solution $n = N$ and $m = N-1$. This leaves us with $(k_1+1)(k_2+1)\cdots(k_r+1)-1$ ways to factor $2N$ into two distinct positive integers with opposite parity.

Therefore, if $N$ has prime factorization $N = 2^{k_0}p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$, then there are $(k_1+1)(k_2+1)\cdots(k_r+1)-1$ ways to write $N$ as the sum of two or more consecutive positive integers.

Comment: Which is equal to the number of odd factors of $N$ bigger than $1$.

Comment: Isn't it turning polynomial problem into subexponential?

Comment: A brute force approach to this problem is polynomial in $N$, while computing the prime factorization of $N$ is sub-exponential in $\ln N$ (not subexponential in $N$ itself).

Comment: Note that if we don't exclude the trivial solution (where $N$ is just the sum of $N$), then the result is the number of odd divisiors of $N$.

Comment: In $(n-m)(n+m+1)=2N$ the $+1$ is on the wrong side: It's $(n-m+1)(n+m)=2N$

Answer (score 3):

This solution is somewhat similar to the one by JimmyK4542, but it avoids a detour and shows directly that the result (if we include the trivial sum $N=N$) is the number of odd divisors of $N$.

Let $d\mid N$ be an odd divisor of $N$, so $N=d\cdot s$. This yields two representations of $N$ as sums of consecutive integers:

\begin{align}
N&=\left(s-\frac{d-1}2\right)\cdots\left(s+\frac{d-1}2\right)\;,\\
N&=\left(\frac d2-\left(s-\frac12\right)\right)\cdots\left(\frac d2+\left(s+\frac12\right)\right)\;.
\end{align}

The first is a sum of natural numbers if $s\gt\frac{d-1}2$, and the second if $\frac d2\gt s-\frac12$; that is, the first if $2s\gt d-1$ and the second if $2s\lt d+1$. Exactly one of these is fulfilled, so we get exactly one representation of $N$ as a sum of consecutive natural numbers per odd divisor. These are all distinct: Two of the same kind must have the same $d$ and $s$ to coincide; and two of different kinds can’t coincide because the centre is an integer $s$ in the first case and a half integer $\frac d2$ in the second case.

Conversely, each representation of $N$ as a sum of consecutive natural numbers arises in this form, since it is centred either about an integer or about a half integer; in the first case the length is an odd divisor of $N$, and in the second case twice the centre is an odd divisor of $N$.

Thus, there are exactly as many such representations as $N$ has odd divisors.