# Prove that $S(N)$ is equal to the number of odd divisors of $N$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $N$ is a positive integer. Let $S(N)$ denotes the number of distinct ways in which $N$ can be expressed as a sum of consecutive positive integers. For example, $S(9)=3$ as $9=2+3+4,9=4+5,9=9$

Prove that $S(N)$ is equal to the number of odd divisors of $N.$

---

I have seen in all numbers, that I took as example, that the above statement is true. Like for $3,5,7\cdots$ but I am not able to prove it. I gave it a try by induction but I got stuck when it came to find number of odd divisors of the inductive variable. Can anyone please help me with this$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true, e.g. $1 = 1 = 0+1$ has two representations as sums. Maybe you need to clarify your conjecture?

Comment: @ZoeAllen I edited my question

Comment: If your sum starts at $k$ and has $n$ numbers in it the sum is $\frac 12(2k+n-1)n$, for example $3+4+5+6+7+8+9=42=\frac 12\cdot 12 \cdot 7$  so you are interested in prime factorizations of $N$.  If $N$ is an odd prime you have the two sums $\frac {N-1}2+\frac {N+1}2, N$.  Can you show $S(N)$ is multiplicative, so $S(PQ)=S(P)S(Q)$ if $P,Q$ are coprime?  Then can you show it works for powers of a prime?   You can then induct on prime factorizations.

Comment: hmmm I think I just found a duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1100897/1107685

Comment: I posted an answer to the question that I closed this as a duplicate of. The existing answer already solved the problem, but I tried to show more directly that the result is the number of odd divisors of $N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be expressed as the difference of two triangular numbers as
$$N=\frac{n(n+1)}2-\frac{m(m+1)}2$$
for positive integers $m<n$.

This gives
$$m=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1-4\left(2N-n(n+1)\right)}}2$$
which implies that the quantity inside the square root must be a square integer.  Thus there is an integer $u$ such that
$$4n^2 + 4n + 1 - 8N - u^2  =  0$$
and hence, $u$ must be odd.

Solving this, we have
$$n=\frac{-1+\sqrt{8N+u^2}}2$$
Again, this requires that the quantity inside the square root is a square integer, so we have an integer $v$ such that
$$8N  =  v^2 - u^2  =  (v-u)(v+u)$$
and since $u$ is odd, $v$ must also be odd.  Thus we can write this in the form
$$2N=\frac{v-u}2.\frac{v+u}2$$

So we are looking for ways of factoring $2N$ into two factors, $A=(v-u)/2$ and $B=(v+u)/2$ with odd integers $u$, $v$. We have $v=A+B$ and $u=B-A$, so $A$ and $B$ must have opposite parity, i.e., one is odd and one is even.

Thus, the integers $A$, $B$ give a solution if and only if $2N = AB$ and one of $A$, $B$ is odd and the other is even.  Clearly this occurs for any odd
divisor $d$ of $N$, which let's us take $A=d$ and $B=2N/d$ (or vice versa, which ever give $B > A$).  Consequently, the number of ways of expressing $N$ as a sum of consecutive positive integers is equal to the number of odd divisors of $N$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach to this problem:

Let $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Let $x$ be the number of ways $N$ can be expressed as the sum of consecutive positive integers. Now consider **all** integers rather than just positive; then for each arrangement $a + (a + 1) + \dots + (a + i)$, a single other arrangement can be made: $(-a + 1) + \dots + (a - 1) + a + (a + 1) + \dots + (a + i)$, for a total of $2x$ ways. Notice here that no two positive arrangements have the same $a$.

**Claim.** The number of odd-length arrangements after these additions is exactly the number of positive ones.

**Proof.** The number of positive arrangements is $x$, half the total arrangements. Observe that each positive arrangement's counterpart has a different parity, since $2(a - 1) + 1 = 2a - 1$ numbers are added. So half the total arrangements are odd-length, concluding the claim.

Then it suffices to count the number of odd-length arrangements. In each such arrangement, there is a center "mean" term $A$. Specifically, for any arrangement of length $b$, this center number is $\frac{N}{b}$, giving $b$ as an odd divisor. To show that these are the only odd divisors, suppose that $b$ is an odd divisor of $N$; then $bc = N$ for some $c$ and we simply take $c - \frac{b - 1}{2}$ to $c + \frac{b - 1}{2}$. And as established earlier each original starting term is distinct, so it must follow that $A$ is too.

Thus, $x$ $A$'s are obtained distinctly (and at a one-to-one ratio) from $x$ odd-length arrangements, exactly the number of odd divisors of $N$.