# Maximum length of consecutive numbers that added up to N

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

how can i find Maximum length of consecutive numbers that added up to N

as example
if N is 15
then we have :

1. 1+2+3+4+5 = 15
2. 7+8 = 15
3. 4 + 5 +6 = 15
   then the maxmum length is 5

if N = 27 : 2+3+4+5+6+7 = 27 so the answer will be 6

is there any fourmla or code can produce the answer
suppose that N could be 1e16

Comment: Well it depends a bit what you mean by "numbers" - particularly whether negative numbers can be included.

Comment: only positive numbers

Comment: It might be useful to first compute $(n+1)+(n+2)+\dots+(n+m).$

Comment: For odd numbers use the form $(p-r)+ \dots + (p+r)=(2r+1)p$. Think about the odd factors even when $N$ is even. Which positive integers cannot be expressed as the sum of consecutive integers?

Comment: @MarkBennet Powers of 2. Since they contain no odd factors, you will never be able to sum consecutive integers to a power of 2.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that an upper bound is producible. The maximum length of consecutive integers that sum to $N$ will at most be the index of the largest triangle number equal to or less than $N$. This is because a sum of more integers will at least equal the next triangle number, which will be greater than $N$. For example: $N = 35 > 28 = \frac{7(7+1)}{2}$. The largest triangle number less than 35 is 28, the 7th triangle number. So, the theoretical maximum length is 7 numbers. Any sum of 8 consecutive numbers will be at least the 8th triangle number, 36, which is greater than 35.

Answer (score 1):

As shown at [Sum of consecutive numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100897/), there is one such representation of $N$ per odd divisor of $N$. If $d$ is an odd divisor of $N$, with $d\cdot s=N$, then

$$
\begin{align}
N&=\left(s-\frac{d-1}2\right)\cdots\left(s+\frac{d-1}2\right)\;,\\
N&=\left(\frac d2-\left(s-\frac12\right)\right)\cdots\left(\frac d2+\left(s+\frac12\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$

are two representations as sums of integers. The first is a sum of positive integers if $2s\gt d$, and the second if $2s\lt d$. The length of the first is $d$, and the length of the second is $2s$, so the length of the one that consists of positive integers is $\min(d,2s)=\min\left(d,\frac{2N}d\right)$.

Thus, the length of the longest such sum is

$$
\max_d\sqrt{2N}\exp\left(-\left|\log\frac d {\sqrt{2N}}\right|\right)\;,
$$

where $d$ runs over all odd divisors of $N$. In other words, find the odd divisor $d$ of $N$ that’s closest to $\sqrt{2N}$ in a multiplicative sense, i.e. whose logarithm is closest to the logarithm of $\sqrt{2N}$, and use $\min\left(d,\frac{2N}d\right)$. (It follows that the maximal length is less than $\sqrt{2N}$, which is roughly the upper bound suggested by Ami Ashman in a comment.)