Writing an Integer as the Sum of an Arithmetic Sequence

Theorem: the number of ways to write an integer $k$ as the sum of consecutive natural numbers (including just $k$ itself) is equals to the number of odd factors of $k$ since every odd factor leads to a construction for the sum of consecutive numbers equal to $k$.

I was wondering, is there a general, closed-form expression for the number of ways to expression $k$ as the sum of terms of an increasing arithmetic sequence of natural numbers. For a sequence of $n$ terms:
$$n(2a+(n-1)d) = 2k$$
I am guessing the answer might have something to do with the factors of $2k$, but I am not sure. I would appreciate any help with this.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100897/sum-of-consecutive-numbers

Yes, I already mentioned that result. I am wondering about a generalization to arithmetic sequences, not just consecutive integers.

Note that you can choose $n,d$ however you want, then solve for $a$ to get an expression, so there are infinitely many ways to express any $k$ this way.

I fixed the problem statement. I might be remembering incorrectly, but I recall seeing a formula for this somewhere, but I lost the source. I am trying to see if I can get some help deriving it.

Surely it is only possible to produce a positive integer as a sum of positive integers. The same comment applies to the linked question too.
